# cancel tab closing in p:accordionPanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, accordion

I have a p:accordionPanel and inside of each tab of the panel there is some info that the user can manipulate, what i need to do is if the user close the tab show a confirm dialog (before the tab get closed) whit something like "are you sure you wanna close the tab? if you do your changes will be lost". here is what i tried

```
<p:ajax event="tabClose" onstart="return myFunction()" 
listener" {myBean.myMethod}" process="@this" />
```

---

```
function myFunction() {
    var answer = confirm("are you sure you wanna close the tab? if you do your changes will be lost");
    if(answer){
        //some logic 
        return true;
    }else{
        //some logic
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if i choose cancel on the confirm dialog the tab get close anyway. Shouldn't the tab closing be canceled by the `onStart="return false"`? is there a way to achieve what i'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem, apparently the `onStart="return false"` does not prevent the tab from change its statatus but the `onTabChange` attribute of the `p:accordionPanel` does, the only problem is that for some reason the `onTabchange` event of the accordion don't get execute when the tab is been closed just when the tab is been opened so i have to override the acordionPanel unselect function of primefaces to call the onTabChange event

```
PrimeFaces.widget.AccordionPanel.prototype.unselect = (function(index) {
  var cached_function = PrimeFaces.widget.AccordionPanel.prototype.unselect;

  return function() {
    var panel = this.panels.eq(index);

    if(this.cfg.onTabChange) {
        var result = this.cfg.onTabChange.call(this, panel);
        if(result === false)
            return false;
    }

    var result = cached_function.apply(this, arguments); 

    return result;
  };
})();
```

then i only had to placed `myFunction();` on the onTabChange event of the accordiong panel (`onTabChange="return myFunction()"`)and it works.