# Handle the update after cell editing in datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to restrict cell editing in datatable to perform the update, I mean to override the action that it takes when we blur from the cell editing.

I tried to use onblur and in this method as following :

```
$(".ui-cell-editor-input input").blur(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
```

but its always performs the update, and I can't find the ajax event to handle when it performs the update since the only one I know is `onCellEdit` which takes action after the update is done.

In other words, how can I do some validation before the update is performed and how the datatable does that update ?

Comment: try removing the existing jquery blur event

Answer (score 1):

You can try modifying the primefaces component function, i had a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423527/cancel-tab-closing-in-paccordionpanel/37599873#37599873)  before. I think the function you shoul take a look is `PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.updateData` check the [code](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/88f9d25ca09dc79bc858ddefe159370477603c47/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js)